# Error number in childnodes in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, child-nodes

Below is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="playground">
        <div id ="player"></div>
    </div>


</body>
```

The div tag with id name "playground" has only one childnode
--div tag with id name "player".

this is my js script

```
window.onload = function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("playground").childNodes.length);
  console.log(document.getElementById("playground").childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  for(i=0;i<document.getElementById("playground").childNodes.length;i++)
  {
   console.log(document.getElementById("playground").childNodes[i]);
  }

}
```

and the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mmBI.png)

but this result show the div tag with id name playground has 3 childnodes 
I have no idea why about this fail:

Comment: You have these nodes in your console, click a small triangle beside each one and look what's in there (spoiler: those are text nodes with whitespace).

Comment: There are 3 nodes, not 1. The space before and after the element are represented as text nodes. You can use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` to get only the Element nodes.

Comment: If you want only one child do this : `<div id="playground"><div id ="player"</div></div>`

Comment: use .children instead of .childNode

Comment: [**childnodes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) -> *"...also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them, use `ParentNode.children` instead."*